# after click have one function for small screen size and one function for big screen size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, screen-size

I'm trying to find a way to open a hidden div on another position in the DOM if the screen size is below 480px.
So far I'm moving the hidden div with an attendTo function for the bigger screen. That is working fine, the only problem is I can't seem to get the hidden div not to move and open in it's original place in the DOM at a smaller screen size.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//determin window width
var width = $(window).width();

//hidden member info
$("div[id=member1]").click(function(){
        $(".member_info:not(#hidden_member1_info)").hide("blind",{direction:"up"}, "slow");
        if ((width >= 480)){
            $("div[id=hidden_member1_info]").appendTo("div[id=hidden_member_closer]");
            $("div[id=hidden_member1_info]").toggle("blind","slow");
            } 
        else{
            $("div[id=hidden_member1_info]").toggle("blind","slow");
            }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have commented the code that handle whether the div appears or not, so I don't expect it to work properly, try uncommenting the if lines.

Comment: sorry i commented those out in my script.js file because it wasn't working. I have uncommented them now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of js libraries for working with media queries in js, and they seem to do what you're looking for.

I think the most famous is [Enquire](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) but there are other options too.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved this problem, and the resize window problem as well by changing the script a little bit. So in case anybody wabts to know here you go.

```
$("div[id=member1]").click(function(){ 
var width = $(window).width(); 
$(".member_info:not(#hidden_member1_info)").hide("blind",{direction:"up"}, "slow"); 
if ((width >= 480)){ 
    $("div[id=hidden_member1_info]").appendTo("div[id=hidden_member_closer]");
} 
$("div[id=hidden_member1_info]").toggle("blind","slow"); });
```

This works perfectly... This way the javaScript checks the window width after the click. Since people can't really resize after a click it also works on a resized browser window.